# How to type hint a function which takes a callable and its required positional arguments?

Tags: python, mypy, python-typing

Here is my function:

```py
def call_func(func, *args):
    return func(*args)
```

I think I have two options here:

1. Using `TypeVarTuple` -> in `Callable[[*Ts], Any]` form.

   ```py
   Ts = TypeVarTuple("Ts")
   T = TypeVar("T")

   def call_func(func: Callable[[*Ts], T], *args: *Ts) -> T:
       return func(*args)
   ```

   Currently Mypy has problem with `[*Ts]` part. it says: `Invalid type comment or annotation`. (I also enabled `--enable-incomplete-feature=TypeVarTuple`.)
2. Using `ParamSpec` -> in `Callable[P, Any]` form.

   ```py
   P = ParamSpec("P")
   T = TypeVar("T")

   def call_func(func: Callable[P, T], *args: P.args) -> T:
       return func(*args)
   ```

   This time Mypy says: `ParamSpec must have "*args" typed as "P.args" and "**kwargs" typed as "P.kwargs"`. It looks like it wants me to also specify `kwargs`.

What is the correct way of doing it? Is there any technical difference between using `TypeVarTuple` and `ParamSec` in `Callable`?

Comment: Your first option is correct, and type-checks correctly on pyright. mypy's support for [PEP 646](https://peps.python.org/pep-0646) is incomplete. I'm not sure why you're getting "Invalid type comment or annotation", but the syntax `*args: *Ts` is for Python >= 3.11 only; in earlier versions you should use `*args: typing_extensions.Unpack[Ts]`.

Comment: The second options is _not_ correct because `ParamSpecArgs`/`ParamSpecKwargs` must always be used in conjunction, as the error correctly pointed out. (See [PEP 612](https://peps.python.org/pep-0612/#id1)) Therefore the difference is substantial.

Comment: Thanks for your responses. So using Mypy, I'm out of luck here right? I need to wait for future releases because currently it doesn't accept the first option.

Comment: You're not out of luck - `ParamSpec` can be made to work to type-check this, if I understand your problem correctly, but it'll not be very intuitive to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to fully type-check something that only accepts positional-only arguments is with [PEP 646](https://peps.python.org/pep-0646), which mypy (as of the time of this answer) does not fully implement. However, you can manipulate `typing.ParamSpec` and `typing.Protocol` to make positional-only and keyword-only callable types which throw errors at a call site if someone tries to pass keyword and positional arguments, respectively.

The core idea is to form a union with `Callable[P, R]` with some `Protocol` `CallbackProto` such that:

- `Callable[P, R]` unioned with `CallbackProto::__call__(self, *args: typing.Any) -> R` rejects all attempts to pass any keyword arguments;
- `Callable[P, R]` unioned with `CallbackProto::__call__(self, **kwargs: typing.Any) -> R` rejects all attempts to pass any positional arguments.

---

In your case, let's say that this was the desired output:

```py
P = ParamSpec("P")
R = TypeVar("R")

def call_func(func: Callable[P, R], *args: P.args, **kwargs: P.kwargs) -> R:
    return func(*args)

>>> def function_(a: int, b: str) -> None:
...     ...
...
>>> call_func(function_, 1, "")  # OK
>>> call_func(function_, 1, b="")  # Unexpected keyword argument "b"
```

This can be done by making `call_func` reject all attempts to pass keyword arguments:

```py
from __future__ import annotations

import typing as t

if t.TYPE_CHECKING:
    import collections.abc as cx

P = t.ParamSpec("P")
R = t.TypeVar("R")
CallFuncT = t.TypeVar("CallFuncT", bound="CallFunc")

class PositionalOnlyCallable(t.Protocol):
    def __call__(self, *args: t.Any) -> t.Any:
        ...

class CallFunc(t.Protocol):
    def __call__(self, func: cx.Callable[P, R], *args: P.args, **kwargs: P.kwargs) -> R:
        ...

def asPositionalOnlyCallable(f: CallFuncT, /) -> CallFuncT | PositionalOnlyCallable:
    """
    No-op decorator which manipulates the typing signature. Unions
    a given callable's type with something which only accepts
    positional arguments.
    """
    return f

@asPositionalOnlyCallable
def call_func(func: cx.Callable[P, R], *args: P.args, **kwargs: P.kwargs) -> R:
    return func(*args)
```

```py
>>> def function_(a: int, b: str) -> None:
...     ...
...
>>> call_func(function_, 1, "")  # OK
>>> call_func(function_, 1, b="")  # mypy: Unexpected keyword argument "b" for "__call__" of "PositionalOnlyCallable" [call-arg]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm still wondering how `CallFuncT | PositionalOnlyCallable` could solve the problem... The returned value of `asPositionalOnlyCallable` which is `f`, "can" be `CallFuncT` and it accepts kwargs. what is the rationale behind this?

Comment: @S.B But `PositionalOnlyCallable` *doesn't* accept keyword arguments. If you have a callable type which can either accept or reject keyword arguments, then it's unsafe to call it with keyword arguments, because it may fail. This is the exact same idea as a type like `my_var: str | list` - `my_var` either has or doesn't have an `.append` method, so the type checker warns you if you try to use `my_var.append`, because it may fail.