# How to forward generic argument types to a callable in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-typing

I want to annotate a generic function which takes as arguments another function and its parameters.

```
def forward(func, **kwargs):
    func(**kwargs)
```

So, if I have a function which takes two integers:

```
def sum_int(a: int, b: int):
    ...
```

in my editor I want help if I pass the wrong object types:

```
forward(sum_int, 1.5, 2.6)   # want type checker to complain about using floats instead of integers
```

How can I annotate `forward`? Something like:

```
def forward(func: Callable[rest, ret], **kwargs: rest] -> ret:
    ...
```

So, the first argument to `forward` is `func` and the `rest` are the keyword arguments. The return is `ret`. But `rest` and `ret` are also the keyword arguments and return type for `func`.

I used to do generics years (decades!) ago in C++, and there were tricks for capturing and unpacking various types, but I don't know whether we have to jump through those kind of hoops with Python, or whether it's even possible.

I don't really know what to search for, and didn't turn up anything anywhere near helpful.

Thanks!

Comment: you want a `typing.ParamSpec`

Comment: See also: *[How to type hint a function which takes a callable and its required positional arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76644359)*. The answer there is quite decent, even though it doesn't work with Pyright.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `typing.ParamSpec` to associate the arguments expected by `func` with the arguments expected by `forward`, though you do apparently need to use both positional and keyword arguments in the definition of `forward`:

```
RV = TypeVar('RV')
P = ParamSpec('P')


def forward(func: Callable[P, RV], *args: P.args, **kwargs: P.kwargs) -> RV:
    ...


def foo(*, a: int, b: int) -> str:
    ...

forward(foo, a=3, b=5)  # OK
forward(foo, 3, 5)  # Not OK, too many positional arguments for foo
```

Comment: Unfortunately for me, I'm currently stuck on Python 3.9., and [**`typing.ParamSpec`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.ParamSpec) is only available since 3.10.

Comment: @PeterWood Import it from [`typing_extensions`](https://pypi.org/project/typing-extensions/) then.

Comment: As an aside, I would push to make newer versions of Python available. Upgrading from one 3.x to another is not the Herculean task that migrating from 2.x to 3.x was, and tooling exists to make it easy to test (and release/deploy) your code as newer releases become available. 3.9 was released nearly 3 1/2 years ago, and Python 3.12 has been out for a few months.

Comment: @chepner it's complicated. The software I'm automating supports Python 2.7, 3.7, 3.8, and 3.9. The next version of the software supports only 3.11. My clients have a laborious requisitioning process. With the last software update (which allowed us to move from Python 2.7 to 3.9) the software's file format also changed. We have many components in a workflow pipeline, and they all need to be coordinated with the same file format. There are other issues, but you get the idea . Yes, there are probably mitigating designs, but I'm not a genius, just trying to get things working.