# How to annotate **kwargs in a wrapper function?

Tags: generics, python-typing

I want to create a wrapper function that passes it's **kwargs to the wrapped
function.
i.e:

Code sample in [pyright playground](https://pyright-play.net/?code=GYJw9gtgBALgngBwJYDsDmUkQWEMoDCAhgDYlEBGJApgFC0Am1wUA7iEQgtSANoAqAGigAqEfwD6Aa1ZEQaAM4BdABTAUALkKlyVagOmz5C4fyXCZcxVsmXjASigBaAHxR%2BG2lG9QQ1GACuIChQ6ipidor2QA)

```py
from typing import Callable

def wrapper[T, **T_kwargs](fn: Callable[T_kwargs, T], kwargs: T_kwargs) -> T:
    return fn(**kwargs)
```

pyright errors:

```
ParamSpec is not allowed in this context
Arguments for ParamSpec "T_kwargs@wrapper" are missing  (reportCallIssue)
```

Is this possible or I'll have to create a `TypedDict`?

Comment: As it happens, see [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77902775/21305238) which was asked just a few hours earlier.

Comment: I'm not saying this is a dupe though. AFAIK, there is currently no way to "pack" `P.kwargs` back to `TypedDict`.

Answer (score 1):

This is possible, but not with only `kwargs` I believe. `ParamSpec` supports this passthrough feature but only if `args` and `kwargs` are both passed through. I'm not sure this limits the flexibility of the function though - see below:

```py
from typing import Callable

def wrapper[T, **P](fn: Callable[P, T], *args: P.args, **kwargs:P.kwargs):
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)

def test(*, arg1: bool, arg2:bool) -> int:
    return 1

wrapper(test, arg1=True, arg2=False)
```